# Bind 9.8 not loading - '/var/cache/bind' failed: file not found

Tags: debian, bind

I have compiled Bind 9.8 on Debian, and am having difficulty getting the daemon to load. Output of `more /var/log/daemon.log | grep named` is as follows (I have isolated the problem to the following lines):-

```
Jul  3 00:54:07 server1 named[850]: /etc/bind/named.conf.options:2: change directory
to'/var/cache/bind' failed: file not found
Jul  3 00:54:07 server1 named[850]: /etc/bind/named.conf.options:2: parsing failed
Jul  3 00:54:07 server1 named[850]: loading configuration: file not found
Jul  3 00:54:07 server1 named[850]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

EDIT:- Bind 9.7 was installed from the debian repos prior to compiling and installing 9.8, and was removed by `aptitude --purge remove bind9`

Regards,
Jack Hunt

Comment: Seriously? You can't work this out from the error messages you posted? (`change directory
to'/var/cache/bind' failed: file not found` => "Maybe I should create the directory it wants?")... I'm just asking for a *little* effort here.

Comment: And place what in it exactly? If it is looking for a file or files to use in this directory, then what is the point in merely creating an empty directory!

Answer (score 4):

`named.conf.options` is a Debianism, and `/var/cache/bind` is the `directory` that it has configured by default.  That's from your old package install.

Clarify what you did when you compiled and installed the software.  Where did the binaries end up, where did the config files end up, and are you certain that your init script is starting the new version?

Comment: Hi, after installing, the binaries ended up in /usr/local/sbin verified by ./named -v

Comment: I think I have made an error, as the logs were initially moaning about /etc/named.conf not existing, so I symlinked named.conf from /etc/bind. This, I assumed was where the new installation placed its config files. Thanks.

Comment: How would I verify that my init scripts are starting the correct version?

Comment: @VisionIncision Well, where did the init script come from?  I don't believe the BIND source install includes an init script or default config files.  The Debian ones should work, but you might need to tweak them to be appropriate to your install.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry if this is frustrating, but am I right in understanding that you mean the different bind9 scripts in the rc*.d directories? If so, I was under the impression that these would have been set by the source install. If this is not the case, then I assume that they are from the old install. I have not attempted to use BIND before, as you can probably tell. So I am not sure what exactly would require tweaking. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @VisionIncision Well, first off you'll want to make sure that it's actually starting the correct version.  Check if there's a `named` in `/usr/sbin` - having two versions installed is only going to muddy things up.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the /var/cache/bind exists and if the bind user has the right permission to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, no /var/cache/bind does not exist.